# How to make a ListView for a ChatApp to manage all chats?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to create a List to manage all chats in my chat app. My chat app is using firebase. The problem is: Should I use a FlatList and save all data locally in a file or in a firebase database?

Answer (score 1):

Save the data in firebase database. Saving data in a file is unprofessional as databases can handle larger data sets and can be much quicker when handling a large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

Use `firebase` for your chat app which can make everything simpler. For `listview` of `firebase` messages use this method

```
ListView listOfMessages = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);

adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(this, ChatMessage.class,
    R.layout.message, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
@Override
protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
    // Get references to the views of message.xml
    TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
    TextView messageUser = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
    TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

    // Set their text
    messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
    messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());

    // Format the date before showing it
    messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
            model.getMessageTime()));
}
};

listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and for more query do visit this link :
[enter link description here](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397)